# How to handle empty column in row_number partition over by duplicate count logic?

Tags: sql, t-sql

How to handle empty column in row_number partition over by duplicate count logic?

In the below query, ProgramID = 300 will have an empty ProgramName twice. Although there are other row of records as duplicate, i will have to ignore them. I will have to pick only the Empty ProgramName and it's corresponding ProgramId which is appearing twice has to shown only one set of record.

Expected output from this 6 row of inserted records would be 5 row of record. Among those 5, 1 row of record has the empty program name.

```
 if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#t') is not null    
drop table #t

 Create table #t
 (
 ProgramId int,
 ProgramName nvarchar(100),
 ProgramStatus nvarchar(100)
 )

 Insert into #t  ( ProgramId,ProgramName, ProgramStatus ) values ( 100, 'Test100', 'TestCompleted' )
 go
 Insert into #t ( ProgramId,ProgramName, ProgramStatus ) values ( 100, 'Test100', 'TestCompleted' )
 go
 Insert into #t ( ProgramId,ProgramName, ProgramStatus ) values ( 200, 'Test200', 'TestCompleted' )
 go
 Insert into #t ( ProgramId,ProgramName, ProgramStatus ) values ( 200, 'Test200', 'TestCompleted' )
 go
 Insert into #t ( ProgramId,ProgramName, ProgramStatus ) values ( 300, '', 'Progress' )
 go
 Insert into #t ( ProgramId,ProgramName, ProgramStatus ) values ( 300, '', 'TestCompleted' )
 go

 select * from #t
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , In the above query .. expected ID's 100, 200. And for 300 .. only one row of record.  Each Id has duplicate row of record. However, in 300.. we need to pick only one row of record. Will that be possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really about the ROW_NUMBER() as such, the question seems to be about writing up the WHERE clause downstream...

```
with selector as (
  SELECT * 
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProgramName ORDER BY ProgramStatus DESC) as rn
     -- though it would be good to order by something more useful, like timestamp
)
select *
from selector
where rn=1 OR ProgramName != ''
```

Comment: Thank you @megadest.. i missed that OR condition .. which saved me a lot .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Will breaking your query into two help?

```
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        #t 
    WHERE
        ProgramName <> ''  

    UNION ALL  

    SELECT
        ProgramId,
        ProgramName,
        MAX(ProgramStatus) 
    FROM
        #t 
    WHERE
        ProgramName = '' 
    GROUP BY
        ProgramId,
        ProgramName
```

This is getting your desired output, but I just picked one of the two ProgramStatuses based on Max(), you might have to change that